# Combining Starter POMs in Spring Boot

Tags: jersey, spring-data, spring-boot

Are the [Spring Boot Starters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms) meant to be combined? For example, I want to use Jersey and JPA in my Spring Boot application. Everything works OK if I start out with just  `spring-boot-starter-jersey` but when I add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to the POM the build fails with missing dependencies:

```
2015-01-12 15:34:48.731  WARN 9396 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [sample.jersey.SampleJerseyApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:489)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:424)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:591)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:480)
        ... 39 common frames omitted
```

If they aren't meant to be combined, then does it matter which starter to use as the "base" before adding further dependencies?

Comment: There should be nothing preventing you from doing so. I suspect that the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` expects that `spring-webvmc` is on the classpath. Try adding that dependency (or add the `spring-boot-starter-web` as well). Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: I suspect a bad jar file (happens sometimes with dodgy network connections when you download a boatload of new dependencies). There's certainly no dependency on spring web in JPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine, unfortunately there's a [bug in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2345) that means it doesn't.

Assuming that you're using Spring Boot 1.2.1 (the latest version at the time of writing), you can work around the problem by making a couple of configuration changes to your app. Firstly, add the following to `application.properties` in `src/main/resources`:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view: false
```

Secondly, you need to disable `SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration`. You can do so using the `exclude` attribute on `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication`. For example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

These two changes disable functionality that's making the faulty assumption that Spring's `spring-webmvc` module will be on the classpath.

An alternative workaround is to add a dependency on `org.springframework:spring-webmvc`, however, as you're using Jersey, you may not want to add this dependency which should be unnecessary.

Comment: Tried both of these things but still having similar issue.