# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class in Spring Configuration Server when running with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-config

I am new to Spring and trying to have a Spring Cloud configuration server, But when i am trying to start server , i am getting below error :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:645) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:635) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.lambda$processDeferredImportSelectors$2(ConfigurationClassParser.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Below is the snippet of Configuration server :-

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below is pom.xml for the project :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Below is the `application.properties` :-

```
server.port=8980
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: post the `.properties` file.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913149/combining-starter-poms-in-spring-boot

Comment: @JonyD i am using Spring boot 2.0.1. In the given link,Solution is for later versions. Still i tried by disabling SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration and adding property "spring.jpa.open-in-view: false" but no luck.

Comment: @MehrajMalik i have just one property "server.port=8980" in application.properties

Comment: Probably a borked jar, purge the local repository. `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and rebuild your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum     Yes It had some incompatible jars in local repository, I deleted the old jars which it is referring. Now Server is started.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri` pointing to some git repository.

---

Example : `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=URL_TOGIT_REPO`

Here is the [youtube link for spring cloud example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2ih5RCuxTM)

Comment: I have it in my bootstrap.properties spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=D:\\Spring_configServer\\config-server